# Query A MySQL Table & Insert Results Into Another Table

Tags: php, mysql

This is my code with comments.

```
//Query the good_keywords table & pick one result at random
$result4 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * from `good_keywords` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1,1");

while($rows4=mysqli_fetch_array($result4)){ 
$tagline = $rows4['keyword'];
}
if (mysqli_num_rows($result4) > 0) {
/*Insert the one result obtained from the earlier query into `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` provided that `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` is empty & `tran_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` is 'post_tag'*/
$result2 = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "UPDATE `tran_term_taxonomy` SET `description` = '{$tagline}' WHERE `tran_term_taxonomy`.`taxonomy` = 'post_tag' AND `tran_term_taxonomy`.`description` = "" LIMIT 1");

echo $tagline;
 }
```

The problem I'm facing is that the page doesn't even load when I run this code & there are no error messages. What is wrong with my code & how do I fix it please?

Thanks.

Comment: Note: The [object-oriented interface to `mysqli`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php) is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface where missing a single `i` can cause trouble. Use this style: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era and should not be used in new code. Additionally the procedural interface has less rigorous error checking and reporting, frustrating debugging efforts.

Comment: Using `$GLOBALS` like this seems like a very heavy-handed approach. That's only necessary in situations where you have a local with precisely the same name, which hopefully you don't. That's also an extremely awkward name for something you'll be using a lot.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](https://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: Tip: You can do an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` clause, so this should be possible in one shot, no fetching/inserting required.

Comment: You've also adopted a dangerous habit of naming things with numbers after them. Either use arrays if you're intending to use that data later on, or recycle the variables when the previous values are no longer relevant. Hoarding variables like this is inefficient, PHP can't release the associated handles and data until they fall out of scope, but replacing them makes them eligible for release immediately.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this...

```
UPDATE tran_term_taxonomy x
 CROSS
  JOIN good_keywords y
   SET x.description = y.keyword
 WHERE x.taxonomy = 'post_tag'  
   AND x.description = "" 
 ORDER 
    BY RAND() LIMIT 1,1
```

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work in PHPMyAdmin. It threw up the following errors:
Unrecognized keyword. (near "x" at position 26)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "CROSS" at position 30)

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query, and edit your question accordingly